# How can I change color of comments if they are next to a table in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, colors

In `org-mode` comments next to a table is same color as the table itself. Would it be possible to change the comments' color if they are next to a table?

For

```
| Timestamp    | Money |
|--------------+-------+
| [2021-19-11] | 195.0 | # -10 BNB
|--------------+-------+
```

I get following output:

[image]

For example in this table, I want to set different color for texts next to `| # <commment>` different than blue.

Comment: You cannot have comments next to a table: try e.g. pressing TAB on that row to reformat the table; the "comment" ends up *IN* the table.

Comment: ... or actually *any* row.

Comment: Seems like `TAB` opens a new item in the table

Comment: It moves to the next field and realigns the table. The point is that everything between the first `|` and the point *after* the newline which follows the last `+` above *is part of the table*: do `(org-element-at-point)` and check what the Org mode parser thinks is the beginning and the end of the table. The "comment" is *part of the table*; it is not a comment (syntactically).

Comment: You are right! like you said `comment` will ends up IN the table. Maybe this will be an ugly hack but my last option would be consider the last column as comment section and change the font color of items in the last column, if possible